# mkproject -t django creates empty directory not a django project

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am just learning how to use `virtualenvwrapper` and after going through the documentation I found that the `mkproject` command can create a new `virtualenv` and a new project. The documentation [also suggests that using a `-t` flag followed by template name would create a project](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensions.html#templates-django). So I thought this should create a django project:

```
mkproject -t django todolist
```

But when I go to my `PROJECT_HOME`, all I see is an empty directory called `todolist`, which was expected to be a django project.

I am confused. Is this even possible? Because `mkproject` command creates a brand new virtual environment where django is not installed. So how could it attempt to create a django project?

Please help me understand this.

Comment: Do you have `virtualenvwrapper.django` installed?

Comment: No. Do I have to manually install that?

Comment: Should I install that in the global python realm (outside any virtualenv)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your question

> So how could it attempt to create a django project?

From [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenvwrapper.django/) of `virtualenvwrapper.django`:

> virtualenvwrapper.django is a template plugin for virtualenvwrapper to
>   create new Django projects automatically. When used with mkproject, it
>   installs Django into the new virtualenv then runs django-admin.py to
>   create a new project skeleton.

As for the reason why you get an empty directory, if you have a look into `virtualenvwrapper`'s source code, the `-t` argument of `mkproject` maps to

```
# ...
i=$(( $i + 1 ));
templates="$templates ${in_args[$i]}";;
# ... 
for t in $templates
do
    echo
    echo "Applying template $t"
    # For some reason zsh insists on prefixing the template
    # names with a space, so strip them out before passing
    # the value to the hook loader.
    virtualenvwrapper_run_hook --name $(echo $t | sed 's/^ //') "project.template" "$envname" "$PROJECT_HOME/$envname"
done
```

So all it does is to run a hook after creating your project. So if the hook (`virtualenvwrapper.django`) doesn't exist, then it's reasonable to expect an empty directory.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I remove both the empty project and the environment `todolist`?

Comment: Just find them in your `$PROJECT_HOME` and `WORKON_HOME` and delete the folders.

Comment: Was hoping for a command. But running `virtualenvwrapper` lists all the available commands where there is a `rmvirtualenv` for `mkvirtualenv` but no `rmproject` for `mkproject`. Ok manually deleting then.